# Запрет вставки строк в таблицу по значениям из другой таблицы

Tags: postgresql, insert, constraints

Есть две таблицы - заказы и перечень услуг. В первой есть поле bool, что заказ утверждён, если он true то во вторую таблицу вставлять/далять значения нельзя.
С изменением первой таблицы и удалением из второй понятно.
В случае  INSERT происходит вставка сразу нескольких значений.

```
INSERT INTO b (a_id, b_value) VALUES (1, 'AA1-BB1'),(1, 'AA1-BB2'),(1, 'AA1-BB3') WHERE (SELECT NOT confirm FROM a WHERE a_id = 1)
```

даёт ошибку
[Вот пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=77b864b2226ef67b342a77079327d3e6)

Как запретить вставлять без триггеров и хранимых процедур?
Можно ли составить как-то сложный constraint или внешний ключ для проверки условия на уровне СУБД?

Answer (score 0):

Пока делаю так.

```
INSERT INTO b (a_id, b_value) SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 'AA1-BB1'),(1, 'AA1-BB2'),(1, 'AA1-BB3')) val WHERE (SELECT NOT confirm FROM a WHERE a_id = 2);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ac6049e1b37ee04346bd9ab058b5e6bf